# How to add custom serialization/deserialization for protobuf?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I have my message definition like

```
message ID {
    string value = 1;
}

message User {
    ID id = 1;
    google.protobuf.StringValue name = 2;
}
```

Now if I serialize an instance of User to json, I get something like this

```
{
    "id": {
        "value" : "myid"
    }
    "name" : "Josh"
}
```

As you can see for the WKT types the value is unnested. However, for my custom message type User the value is nested. How do I make the output look like

```
{
    "id": "myid"
    "name" : "Josh"
}
```

I mean how do I serialize, deserialize to custom type.

One option I could think of is update this function https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/json_format.py#L199
This means, have a copy of json_format.py and extend _IsWrapperMessage to my custom types

Comment: I am also in need of something similar. were you able to figure it out?

Comment: I'm also interesting in it. Proposed an idea here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/29677 

As I think it might be a good idea to add capability to create a custom field type. It might be defined as an abstract class and it has to be implemented for particular languages which you want to use